# Is there any way to invalidate all memcache entries that begin with "User*"?

Tags: cache

I recently made a change to my User class (which is memcached); is there any way I can invalidate all entries whose key begins with `User` without invalidating the entire cache?

If not are there any workarounds? I would rather not delete everything.

Comment: You'll probably get a faster response over at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [memcached FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ), [**Deleting by Namespace**](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Deleting_by_Namespace):

> While memcached does not support any
>   type of wildcard deleting or deletion
>   by namespace (since there are not
>   namespaces), there are some tricks
>   that can be used to simulate this.
>   They do require extra trips to the
>   memcached servers however.
>
> Example, in PHP, for using a namespace
>   called foo:

```
$ns_key = $memcache->get("foo_namespace_key");
// if not set, initialize it
if($ns_key===false) $memcache->set("foo_namespace_key", rand(1, 10000));
// cleverly use the ns_key
$my_key = "foo_".$ns_key."_12345";
$my_val = $memcache->get($my_key);

//To clear the namespace do:
$memcache->increment("foo_namespace_key");
```

If you are planning on doing a blanket clear of only part of the cache, you might consider setting the expiry to a shorter time period.

Answer (score 2):

As memcached does not have namespace or something like delete/query by wildcards, you can do this trick: save all keys starts with namespace "user_" in a key.

For example

```
$keys = array('user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3');
$memcache->set('user_', $keys);
```

Now when you want to delete all keys starts with "user_", just get key "user_" first. By doing that, you have all keys you want do delete

```
$all_keys = $memcache->get('user_');
if($all_keys){
    foreach($all_keys as $key){
        $memcache->delete($key);
    }
}
```